# WPF DataGrid cell style from different property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to bind a data grid column value to one property of the bound class specified in ItemsSource, but reference a different property in that class to style the cell?

Here is a code example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="MyCollection">
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding={Binding ColumnText} />
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn2" Binding={Binding ColumnText2} />
</DataGrid>
```

Suppose that I have a two further properties (Enum or Brush) in the objects in MyCollection that I want to refer to to set the background colour of the respective cells; can this be done?

EDIT - I need to do this for multiple columns, each looking at a different property to ascertain the colour it should be; I have added a second column to the code example above.

I know I can set the style based on the value in ColumnText, but that is not what I need to do.

I have tried setting a style data trigger, but when I try to bind, I can only bind to something from the overall data context, not to another property within the object that is populating the current row.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to set a cell background by a property from the Row model.

You can achieve this by setting a cell style, and set a *DataTrigger* to that style to bind to a property you want.

---

### Example

You want to make each cell, that has the number 3 to be painted green:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Number}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

And, of course, you can change the ***Number*** property with your own property, and the value you are interested in.

If you want to do something more complex, like range of values and such, you should go with the conventional converters way.

---

### Edit

If you want to make a different cell style for each column, you should explicitly set columns:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Number}" Value="3">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

One important thing to notice though,

You **have** to set *AutoGenerateColumns="False"* or else the columns will generate twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse! I realise I haven't been clear in my question, I need to do this in multiple columns, each referring to a different property to set its colour.

Comment: I tried your example and in the data trigger I cannot bind to a property of the row, only to properties of the outer data context object.

Comment: I've added my answer to be for an explicit column

Comment: Thanks for the update! I get the same issue as before, though. In the DataTrigger, I can only bind to properties of the outer data context (the viewmodel that is available throughout the XAML) and not to another property of the row.

Comment: I guess you mean that the auto-completion doesn't let you. But don't worry, I think it's a bug of the Visual Studio or something like that.
Feel free to put the name of your Property, compile, and let the magic happen. :)

Comment: Ha, yes! Thanks, that seems to work. If only Intellisense could pick that up, would have saved me ages.